# Solving for two unknowns?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{cases}
c_1+c_2=1 \\
c_1(1+\sqrt6)+c_2(1-\sqrt6)=4  \\
\end{cases}$$

$$c_1=\frac{2+\sqrt6}{4},$$

$$c_2=\frac{2-\sqrt6}{4}.$$

Hello I am trying to understand how did reach on this result but I can't get it. For sure it divide with 4, but it doesn't make sense to me the whole.

I have the same thing $c_1+c_2=1$  and $c_1((6+1)/4) +  c_2((6-1)/4)=0$,  and I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: This is just a standard linear system.  Think of it as $X+Y=1$, $AX+BY=4$ for constants $A,B$.  Now solve for $X,Y$ in terms of $A,B$.

Comment: you are saying that AX=-BY+4,  SO X=(-BY+4)/A . This would be the X which represents C1.Did I get it this right?

Comment: You need values for $X,Y$ in terms of $A,B$.  We already know $Y=1-X$ but it's not enough to get them in terms of each other.

Comment: Alt. hint: write the second equation as $\;\underbrace{(c_1+c_2)}_{=\, 1}+\sqrt{6}\,(c_1-c_2)=4\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial answer:** Removing $(1-\sqrt{6})$ times the first equation to the second one yields an equation without $c_2$, specifically
$$2\sqrt{6}c_1=3+\sqrt{6}\,,$$

which yields $$c_1 = \frac{\sqrt{6}+2}{4}\,.$$

Comment: first equation ? which is the first equation?

Comment: the one in the top, $c_1+c_2=1$

Comment: If i got it right, you are saying first equation :(1−√6)C1 +C2(1-√6)=1  and you add the second equation ?

Comment: $(1-\sqrt{6})c_1+(1-\sqrt{6})c_2=1-\sqrt{6}$, and I remove that from the second one

Comment: something goes wrong on me,I have if I remove the second I have c1 + 2√6c2=3+√6 if I solve it c1=(3+√6)/2√6c2 ...am I wrong somewhere

Comment: Indeed your result is wrong. If you detail your computations I might be able to help.

Comment: I have (1-√6)c1  remove the second equation -(1+√6)c1 it makes c1. Now the c2(1-√6)  i remove the second equation the same part -c2(1-√6) I have -2√6c2 . Now the last ,the first equation the  1 becomes (1-√6)*1  and I remove the second equation which is 4,and I have -4+1 -√6 which it does -3-√6.

Comment: It seems to me you have the correct computations written down, but make mistakes when you carry them out.

Comment: Try solving the following system: $x+y=1$ and $2x+3y=5$. If you manage to do this, then you will have the method for answering your question, only the computations become slightly harder.